# Using the As keyword v explicitly defining an interface

Tags: c#

I am looking at some code like this:

```
var Person = new Person() as IPerson;
```

Is there any benefit doing the above over doing this:

```
IPerson IPerson = new Person();
```

The only benefit I can see is that the As keyword allows you to follow the `var` convention when coding.  Is it normal practice to use the as keyword like this just to follow the var convention or is there another benefit?

I have read this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/as.  I understand the benefit of using `As` if I have an object (like in the example), however I cannot see any benefit of the code above, so I must be missing something.

Comment: I dont think it makes a difference wrt your code. Returning/accepting an interface for a method makes more sense.

Comment: The 'as' should just be used when you are not sure if the value implements the interface or not - when you have logic to handle both cases. Otherwise you should cast (IPerson)value for example - as an error here should be visible as soon as possible. In your example i would stick to var without as.

Comment: Anyhow using `var Person = new Person();` shouldn't matter as if you need to pass the object to method that require a `IPerson` you will be able to pass it directly.

Comment: Your first code will pass a compile time check if `Person` doesn't implement `IPerson` but the second won't compile at all, so in this case I would go with the latter for type safety.

Comment: I was just about to post an answer... too long for comments. [here is a link to it on text-share.com](https://text-share.com/view/b0ead455)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the class already implements the interface, there is no benefit to using `as`. The runtime casting operation will actually not happen (it is optimized away by the compiler) only the type will be used to infer the type of the variable.

`As` has a benefit if you do not know at runtime the type of the object

```
object p = new Person();
object o = "Test";
var pp = p as IPerson // will not be null, at runtime p will actually contain a person (even if it declared as object)
var oo = o as IPerson // will be null because the o is actually a string
```

Comment: So if I declare a person in a local test method (were I tend to use vars by convention), then I should use:  IPerson IPerson = new Person(); ? Is that right.

Comment: @w0051977 I would use `IPerson IPerson = new Person()`, because `as` implies a runtime cast for me, which this is not. But from a generated code point of view it makes no difference which you use

Comment: So just to be clear.  You would use var normally, but IPerson in this specific scenario?

Comment: @w0051977 yes, that sounds about right, you can use `var` when you want to type the variable with the same type as the initialization expression. If the type differs you should specify it explicitly

Comment: @w0051977: var is just a shorthand for writing the full type. The compiler will infer the type of the variable, based on the right hand of the expression. pp and oo as as strongly type as if you had written the fully qualified name of the type (YourNamespace.IPerson).